# Why is parseInt and parseFloat in two places?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

It can be found on both the global variable window as well as Number?

Is there a reason for this?

Are they aliases?

Global Implementation - parseInt

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Number Implementation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt

Number Implementation - parseInt

Comment: All these 3 methods (`Number`, `parseInt`, `parseFloat`) have different semantics.

Comment: I don't see any obvious differences in `Number.parseInt` and `window.parseInt`, they both take a string followed by an optional radix.  The docs are a bit inaccurate in this regard as `window.parseInt` should show this parameter to be optional as it is not required.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your original post. [They are both the same](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number.parsefloat)

Answer (score 1):

The initial definition of ECMAScript defined `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` in global namespaces.

But since polluting the global namespace came to be an anti-pattern, the two methods were moved to `Number` object in ECMAScript 2015 (6th edition).

For backwards compatibility, the two methods are still in the global namespace.

ECMAScript 6
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.parseint

Comment: Seems like Infinity was "deprecated" for it's positive and negative values as well - both on Number as well.

Comment: @brannonteer Thanks, didn't realize that.